# How to publish a table in dolphinDB?

Tags: streaming, dolphindb

i have a table like following in DolphinDB server:

```
n=100000
t=streamTable(rand(100,n) as id ,rand(100.0,n) as val)
share t as st;
```

How can I get the data in client, and the clint isn't a DolphinDB node.

Answer (score 0):

If the client isn't a DolphinDB data node, please use corresponding language API to subscribe streaming table on DolphinDB data node. The supported API languages include Java, C++，c#, Go, Rust, Python, R and web。Go https://github.com/dolphindb to get corresponding language api.